# AndroidGameView + GC_MINOR

Tags: android, opengl-es, mono, xamarin, monogame

I have a fairly complex OpenGL based app which uses `AndroidGameView` for setting up the drawing contexts, etc. I noticed that at some point in the past (it was not always like this) that I started getting constant `GC_MINOR` messages in the console when testing the app on a Nexus 7 every second or two.

I also noticed that the basic template project for "Android OpenGL Application" (in Xamarin Studio) also suffers from a similar problem. Creating a brand new project from this template and running it on hardware results in the following messages in the console when the app is just sitting there and running:

```
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE num-objects 8 num_hash_entries 8 sccs size 8 init 0.00ms df1 0.12ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.24ms setup-cb 0.03ms free-data 0.03ms user-cb 26.49ms clenanup 0.12ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 16/8
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 51.85ms, total 52.00ms, bridge 26.98ms promoted 848K major 1120K los 186K
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 49.65ms, total 49.80ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 544K major 1664K los 186K
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 50.72ms, total 50.93ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 544K major 2208K los 186K
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 84.78ms, total 85.02ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 560K major 2768K los 186K
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 58.10ms, total 58.23ms, bridge 0.03ms promoted 560K major 3328K los 186K
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 49.32ms, total 49.47ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 544K major 3872K los 186K
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE num-objects 1 num_hash_entries 1 sccs size 1 init 0.00ms df1 0.24ms sort 0.03ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.03ms user-cb 25.57ms clenanup 0.12ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 18/9
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 135.53ms, total 135.77ms, bridge 25.82ms promoted 560K major 4432K los 186K
```

My question is: why is this happening? I'm sure it has something to do with the underlying `AndroidGameView` but it was not always like this. In my actual app the constant GC'ing is having a negative impact on the overall graphics performance (it seems to "hiccup" quite a bit as the `GC_MINOR` pauses for 50-100ms).

Answer (score 0):

I think Xamarin fixed this behavior in 5.1

Have a look - https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#GC-free-Method_Invocations

Previously they allocated some .NET wappers on Java objects every Update/Draw call. To my mind allocation rate was about 5-10kb per second. 
This could lead to GC every minute or about that.